# Database Schema

Tags: java, sql, database, schema

If I have a file/folder and I want have different users be able to access it...
i.e Folder one can be accessed by J, K and M....

Should the file/folder have its own table with a list of users who can access it, or should each user have a list of files/folders they can access.

I want to bare in mind extensibility when it comes to the database.
 I just cant see which would be the best thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a database, it is exactly the same space:
Imagine 1million folders with 3 person:
At maximum: 1million / person or 3person / million which equals to 3millions in db.
If you have in mind extensibility, think of what you're going to add the most, folders or people. If you're adding a lot of folders, it's easier to put the people that can access the folder attached with the folder, if you're adding a lot of people, it's better to have all the folder a person can access attach with the person so when you create a new folder/person you can directly give him the rights/persons.

Comment: Thanks for thee reply, what is the common practice for large file sharing sites. I will roughly have 20,000 users?

Comment: You will have, I think, more files than users.
So it's better to attach the users that can access a file to the file.

Comment: And I think it's safer, imagine you have an user that want to share a file with his friend, you just have to add the friend to the allowed user list. If you do the opposite, you have to add the file to the user files list. Deleting the file would make a lot of complications with the rights of each persons.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, now if I do attach the user who can access a file to the file, how can I allow users have different permission to a file i.e read only, write etc

Comment: A way to do it is to make a table per file, this table will have for columns:
id_user, rights, admin?
So for each new person you can write their rights and if they have admin rights(delete ect) on the file.

Comment: Ok so when I create a file a table is created. I need to then have a list of people who can access it. But a table in a datbase cannot store a list. WOuld it not be unefficient to have to create a new table with every file with users allowed to access it

Comment: A table in a database CAN store a list !!!!!!
I gave you the columns, the "list" of users, are the lines ! 1 line = 1 user !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91015/discussion-between-axel-lavielle-and-hat-to-the-back).

Comment: If my table for each file uploaded is this
File
parent_id / name / id / classType


If you do it your way then wont there be a table for every file, which means if there are 10 files then there 10 tables?